# NoAi Chicken won't activate pressure plate

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help creating a device that sends "`NoAI:1b`" chickens over pressure plates to make music. Unfortunately, either the chickens are not technically touching the ground or some how the lack of AI really messes things up (or something else).

The chickens are teleported along a track that sends them over the pressure plate shown here:

[image]

And here are the codes to teleport the chicken forward, back to the beginning of the track, and to summon them. Respectively.

`execute as @e[type=chicken,distance=..33.5] at @e[type=chicken,distance=..33.5] run tp @s[distance=..0.5,type=chicken] ~ ~ ~.25`

`execute as @e[type=chicken,name=nC] at @e[type=chicken,name=nC] if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:repeating_command_block run tp @s[distance=..0.5,type=chicken] ~ ~ ~-31`

`summon minecraft:chicken 654 65 316 {CustomName:"\"mC\"",CustomNameVisible:1,Health:100,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:100},{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:1f}],Silent:1,NoAI:1,OnGround:1b}`

Any suggestions, tips, or recommendations on the script would be helpful. And I will be willing to answer questions about the design.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using redstone blocks or the /playsound command?

Comment: Building it for a friend, so I want it to look pleasing. Just that. Otherwise I would.

Comment: You could use both. Chickens for visuals, but the actual logic working differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the chicken is not affected by gravity, so removing the `NoAI` tag will help out. The `OnGround` tag is redundant as well. However, the chicken will still be able to move and lay eggs, which may mess stuff up. Here's how you can fix both things:

You can utilize the Movement Speed attribute to force the chicken to stand still, like so:

`Attributes:[{Name:generic.movement_speed,Base:0}]`

Additionally, chickens have a special attribute involving how long until their next egg is laid. Set it to a very high number within your summon command:

`EggLayTime:99999`

You may need to reset this timer occasionally.

Your final /summon command should look like this:

```
summon minecraft:chicken 654 65 316 {CustomName:"\"mC\"",CustomNameVisible:1,Health:100,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:100},{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:1f},{Name:generic.movement_speed,Base:0}],Silent:1,EggLayTime:99999}
```

The other commands should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I only hoped I could keep the chickens uniform by removing their AI's.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tripwire and string. `NoAI` chickens still activate that.