# Keep gravity with NoAI in Minecraft 1.16.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

How do I have gravity affect NoAI entities?  I want to have the Motion still work with a entities with NoAI.  Is this possible?  In 1.9 NoAI no longer prevents gravity, but in 1.16.4, NoAI cancels out gravity regardless of what NoGravity is set to.  I’ve tried setting NoGravity to `0b` which had no success like I said earlier.  I also tried looking help up online, but could only find stuff about the 1.9 update.  If any of this is unclear or you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [NoAi Chicken won't activate pressure plate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372569/noai-chicken-wont-activate-pressure-plate/376018#376018).

Comment: @Name_Hr3 I don't want the entity to move or rotate its head.  This helps, but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Is it okay to use a command to lock the entity's head in place? Say.... /tp @e ~ ~ ~ 90 0?

Comment: @Name_Hr3 I pretty sure the tp command cancels out motion.  I'm trying to use the motion tag so that probably won't work.

Comment: @Name_Hr3 no I tried a command to lock the entity's head rotation. It didn't do anything.

Comment: May I see the command? And what is these "entity(s)?"

Comment: @Name_H3r the command to lock the entity's head Rotation is `data modify entity @e[tag=new,limit=1] Rotation set from entity @p Rotation`.  The entity is a baby turtle with a armor stand riding the baby turtle.  The turtle is also on a team with the collision rule set to never.